# What is the latest official version of Google Guice and where should I get it from?

Tags: maven-2, guice

I downloaded the guice 2.0 source from http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/downloads/list but when I looked at the pom I saw the version was was marked as 1.0-RC2 and the target jar that was build by maven was named guice-1.0-RC2.jar. On the central maven repository under com.google.inject there is a jar named guice-2.0.jar. Under com.jolira the latest version is 2.11 and there is also source and java doc jars. What is the latest official version? I'm also wondering what is the story with the Jolira version - are they modifing the google code or are they just creating releases from the google svn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea what a Jolira version is. The latest official release version of Guice is 2.0. However, version 3.0 is (hopefully) coming sometime in the near future. The Guice trunk has recently (just the other day) been updated to be buildable with Maven, and 3.0-SNAPSHOTs will be available here: https://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/forge/com/google/inject/

Once 3.0 is released, it'll be available in Maven central.